# Angular JS dropdown value refresh when i clicked bootstrap tab clicked without page loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

#### this is my controller:

```
$scope.resultsTab = function() { http.get('rest/dropdownvalues').success(function(data) {
$scope.SelectorName= data; }};
```

#### This is my HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="id1" name="name1" ng-options="data as data.fileName for data in SelectorName" ng-model="item" ng-change="fileNameOnChange()"><option value="" selected>Select a FileName</option></select>
```

I am using angular JS Bootstrap tab, this dropdown there in my second tab.

Now I had added one value in dropdown via backend server.

However, I am not getting my newly added value in my dropdown.

When I refreshing the page that time I can view that newly added value, but I can't get without page loading.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  Adding a new option directly to the backend is not going to reflect in the frontend unless the options are fetched again.

Comment: That is why i asked, how can i fetch the newly added value without page loading.

Comment: Since you are over HTTP, you either need some kind of web socket to push the information to the browser OR you need to re-request the data every time OR you need to poll for it.  Usually, these kinds of requirements are taken care of because *current* users won't get the new values, but *new* users will.

Comment: i should call the REST webservice again and send it in to the drop down using $scope.SelectorName = data; but i can't get the new value in Drop down.